# Project Academic Knowlede | Query for and list papers by AA.AuId?

Tags: academic-graph

I've got a list of author names but I don't have Id's for any of them.

I'd like to:

1. Query by author name and store the most probable AuId.
2. List all papers written by a given AuId.

Is there any way to do this with the current interpret/evaluate APIs? It seems like everything is tied to a paper entity and I want to be sure I am only ever selecting and using one AuId.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only have the author name? Or would you also have other details, such as the institutional affiliation or the year(s) of publications?

Comment: Thanks @anpami. I have author names and institutions, but I do not have specific publication dates. That's why I'm trying to uniquely ID authors and then grab a given author's publications.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a feature. But indirectly, you could first search for the author name (`AA.AuN` in the `expr`-field), obtain all the (unique) various author IDs (`AA.AuId` in the `attributes` field), and search for their publications.

(You could even add `orderby=logprob:desc`, but [to be honest, I am not 100% sure what `logprob` does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667673/in-microsoft-academics-api-what-do-the-logprob-and-prob-fields-mean))

So, the first step could be to search for the author name (e.g. `John Smith`) like this and fetch all those `AA.AuId` where the names (`AA.AuN`) seem to fit `John Smith` (let's just add the `orderby=logprob:desc`):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(AA.AuN=%27john%20smith%27)&count=100&attributes=AA.AuN,AA.AuId&orderby=logprob:desc&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

As a second step, if you have an Author ID `AA.AuId` (here, for example, `3038752200`), use this to list their papers (ordered by year, in a descending manner `orderby=Y:desc`):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(AA.AuId=3038752200)&count=100&attributes=AA.AuN,AA.AuId,DOI,Ti,VFN,Y&orderby=Y:desc&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

---

The approach would be more promising if you had an institutional affiliation as well. Then you could change the `expr` field to `Composite(And(AA.AuN='{AUTHOR-NAME}',AA.AfId={AFFILIATION-ID}))` so as to search for all {AUTHOR-NAMES} affiliated to {AFFILIATION-ID}.